# Не могу подключить css,js к html в django

Tags: javascript, html, python, css, django

[image: пути проекта]

Не могу присоединить стиль css к html. В настройках:

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]`
Cсылка в коде
[image: ссылка на стиль]
Not found выдает браузер по этой ссылке
[image: код ссылки в браузере]

Comment: А что дебагер браузера выдает?

Comment: Похоже совсем другой шаблон рендрится.

Comment: Что имеете ввиду под рендером другого шаблона(новичок)? На скрине выше исходный код ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте! 
Если я правильно понял, вы забыли подключить url'ы для файлов статики (staticfiles). Когда сайт находится в разработке (development) то обязательно надо это сделать. 
**Покажу как** 

В файле url.py:

```
// urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**ДИСКЛЕЙМЕР**

Перед запуском проэкта в продакшн (production) обязательно уберите

```
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

*Очень надеюсь, что помог. Будут вопросы - пишите!*